# What equipment is required to traverse Daisetsuzan in Hokkaido at the end of April?

Tags: japan, gear, mountain-climbing, hokkaido

It looks like there is still snow at Daisetsuzan in Hokkaido at the end of April. I prefer hiking with snow and ice, and have the appropriate equipment, but want to know what to bring (do I need crampons? pitons?).

What is the condition of the snow in that area? Is it hard? Soft? What is the ground on the mountain like underneath the snow? How cold does it get at night, and what is the temperature during the day?

There are many different traverses, so I apologize for not providing the specific one I plan to take.

Comment: JAja, sorry for my english. I referred to crampons

Comment: I would advise to check whether it is "safe" to go there in the end of April. I've been there in the end of June and the temperature was way below the freezing in the mountains during the night and the snow was several meters deep, depending on a place, of course. Places blown by wind were just plain rock. I put safe into "" because it is never perfectly safe there, very harsh although beautiful environment but I am afraid in the end of april there's large risk of avalanches.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might make sense to migrate this to Outdoors SE.